# Alloy - set difference leading to vars and clauses, set union does not

Tags: alloy

I'm curious as to when evaluation sets in, apparently certain operators are rather transformed into clauses than evaluated:

```
abstract sig Element {}
one sig A,B,C extend Element {}

one sig Test {
  test: set Element
}

pred Test1 { Test.test = A+B }
pred Test2 { Test.test = Element-C }
```

and run it for `Test1` and `Test2` respectively will give different number of vars/clauses, specifically:

```
Test1: 0 vars, 0 primary vars, 0 clauses
Test2: 5 vars, 3 primary vars, 4 clauses
```

So although `Element` is `abstract` and all its members and their cardinalities are known, the difference seems not to be computed in advance, while the sum is. I don't want to make any assumptions, so I'm interested in why that is. Is the `+` operator special?

To give some context, I tried to limit the domain of a relation and found, that using only `+` seems to be more efficient, even when the sets are completely known in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To give some context, I tried to limit the domain of a relation and found, that using only + seems to be more efficient, even when the sets are completely known in advance.

That is pretty much the right conclusion. The reason is the fact that the Alloy Analyzer tries to infer relation bounds from certain Alloy idioms.  It uses a conservative approximation that is always sound for set union and product, but not for set difference.  That's why for `Test1` in the example above the Alloy Analyzer infers a fixed bound for the `test` relation (`this/Test.test: [[[A$0], [B$0]]]`) so no solver needs to be invoked; for `Test2`, the bound for the `test` relation cannot be shrunk so is set to be the most permissive (`this/Test.test: [[], [[A$0], [B$0], [C$0]]]`), thus a solver needs to be invoked to find a solution satisfying the constraints given the bounds.

Comment: I wonder if some pre-processing would go a long way. However, I can understand that drawing conclusions about certain sets is easier (or more solid) to be left to the solver.